# Python : "IndexError: list index out of range" Password generator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to create a password generator in python using the secrets module.
I first ask the user the desired length of the password, and then chose randomly between 3 lists of characters (letters, numbers, symbols). I then print the results one by one through a loop.

My problem is that the program works fine until around 12 characters asked by the user. I then get the following error `IndexError: list index out of range` and after searching for hours, I can't manage to find an answer.

Sorry if the question seems basic, but I'm still a beginner, and only want to improve!

Here's my code :

```
import secrets
# importing modules

doRun = True
while doRun:
    length = int(input("How many characters do you want you password to have ? "))
    # Asking the user for the length of the password

    letCar = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
              "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",
              "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    # List for characters
    numCar = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0"]
    # List for numbers
    symCar = ["!", "@", "?"]
    # List for symbols
    password = []
    # Initializing list for password

    for i in range(0, length):
        selector = secrets.randbelow(3)
        # Randomly choosing from which list to pick
        if selector == 0:
            # Characters list
            chosenCar = secrets.choice(letCar)
            password.append(chosenCar)
            letCar.remove(chosenCar)
        elif selector == 1:
            # Numbers list
            chosenCar = secrets.choice(numCar)
            password.append(chosenCar)
            numCar.remove(chosenCar)
        elif selector == 2:
            # Symbols list
            chosenCar = secrets.choice(symCar)
            password.append(chosenCar)
            symCar.remove(chosenCar)

    print("password is : ", end="")
    for i in range(len(password)):
        print(password[i], end="")
    print()
    doRun = input("Again ? (Yes --> True // No --> False) : ")
```

The errors are :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Bureautique\Outils\Programmation\Python\Projects\PWHash\main.py", line 35, in <module>
    chosenCar = secrets.choice(symCar)
  File "C:\Users\Arthur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\random.py", line 347, in choice
    return seq[self._randbelow(len(seq))]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: What was the chosen value of length that triggered the error?

Comment: It starts giving errors when length >= 10, but not everytime. This is what intrigues me, it sometimes prints the result, and sometimes returns an error.
I also get errors for lower values, but it seems to be more rare.

Comment: Zakariyya is right. Also, if you're trying to generate passwords, you're better off putting all the characters in one big list instead of splitting it up, and also don't remove any characters from the list. The best passwords are unpredictable: by removing characters, you're making it easier to guess what the next character is (it can't be any of the characters that were already in the password) and by putting the characters in different lists, you make special characters way more likely to appear than letters

Comment: Well, you are removing items from the lists randomly, so it could crash after 4 times if you remove all of the elements from symCar but the lists could last longer if there is heavy sampling from a longer list like letCar.

Comment: Yes, that will probably work !
Also, thank you for your advice, I will modify this to make the program stronger and less predictable.
In any way, the program wasn't supposed to be used on a daily basis, but was more of a project idea I had that I thought would be fun to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're removing items from the Car lists, so that when a Car is chosen enough times, in the case of the symCars, the line where your program crashed, only 3, and it is then an empty list, so if the Car is selected again there's nothing in the list for the secrets module to find

Comment: Indeed, that might correct the problem, I did not think about this case !
I will try correcting it and will get back to you afterwards.
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's what you're looking for but that's how it worked for me

```
for i in range(0, length):
        selector = secrets.randbelow(3)
        # Randomly choosing from which list to pick
        if selector == 0:
            # Characters list
            chosenCar = secrets.choice(letCar[i])
            password.append(chosenCar)
            letCar.remove(chosenCar)
        elif selector == 1:
            # Numbers list
            chosenCar = secrets.choice(numCar[i])
            password.append(chosenCar)
            numCar.remove(chosenCar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an item from *symCar* is deleted every time an item is selected from it. This empties the list after three repetitions. To fix the problem, you could remove the *.remove* lines. Although this allows for multiple of a single character to be included in your password, this helps keep it unpredictable.

Another option is to add a way for the lists to refill after all of their items have been deleted. An example of this is shown below.

```
if symCar == []:
    symCar = ["!", "@", "?"]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I removed an item from the lists after chosing it. It would sometimes make an empty list, thus the error. I corrected this by making a big list whith all the characters in it, as suggested by Matthew, and I don't remove the chosen characters from the list to make the program less predictable.

The newly edited program is this one :

```
import secrets
import random
# importing modules

doRun = True
while doRun:
    length = int(input("How many characters do you want you password to have ? "))
    # Asking the user for the length of the password

    car = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u",
           "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P",
           "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "!",
           "@", "?"]
    # Characters list

    password = []
    # Initializing list for password

    for i in range(0, length):
        random.shuffle(car)
        password.append(secrets.choice(car))
        # Picking an item form the car list and appending it to the password list after a shuffle

    print("password is : ", end="")
    for i in range(len(password)):
        print(password[i], end="")
    print()
    doRun = input("Again ? (Yes --> True // No --> False) : ")
```

Thank you all for your help !